# /users/recent page does not consistently show all changes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity

I don't know if it's a bug or timezone related, but in order to properly use the /users/recent page I have to click on Yesterday or Last Week to properly see all votes and comments (most likely due to comments received during the night).

In the old layout the links were very visible, but in the new layout they are to subtle for my taste.

Can we have them a bit more obvious again please?

**Edit:** Okay, maybe it's not the look but a different bug. Here are three Screenshots, showing my SO View for Today, Yesterday and This Week. Notice that there are 3 Upvotes that only show up in "This Week", even though they are more recent than the accepted answer that shows up "Yesterday". I'm guessing it's due to a data range overlap. Ideally, I don't want a view for "Yesterday" - instead **I want a view for "Last 24 Hours"**. That's why I use the "This Week" and "Last Week" views a lot, and they are harder to find with the new design. I've renamed the question as it's either a bug or a feature-request.

[Today http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/4117/1today.jpg](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/4117/1today.jpg)

[Yesterday http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/4144/2yesterday.jpg](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/4144/2yesterday.jpg)

[This Week http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/474/3thisweek.jpg](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/474/3thisweek.jpg)

**Edit 2:** I just noticed that there is a difference between the default view and "Today". "Today" shows the proper changes, so the default view is rather useless. I don't know if making the default view to "Today" is a good solution, as I'd still prefer the default view to be "Last 24 hours", as a sliding window.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem (and have since the /users/recent feature was introduced). I click on the envelope and see no activity. I then click on "Today" and an upvoted answer appears. It's like it doesn't default to "Today" (and nor does it remember for next time I visit that page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates are quite clearly outlined at the top of the page; this isn't a bug at all:

> 2009-10-13 07:36:46Z to 2009-10-13 23:59:59Z  (envelope -- implicit "since last login")
>   2009-10-12 00:00:00Z to 2009-10-12 23:59:59Z  (yesterday)
>   2009-10-11 00:00:00Z to 2009-10-13 23:59:59Z  (this week)

I think that the "3h one" is not showing because it isn't in those time ranges. Think about it -- the (this week) is the ONLY view containing the early morning hours of 10-13, before 7:36:46.

That's why you see the entry there, but not in the other views.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after looking closer. Definitely not a bug, but I don't like the design as it's unintuitive for me. I'd still prefer a "Last 24 hours" as the default view :)

Comment: and if you haven't logged in in the last 24 hours? How would that work exactly?

Comment: Perhaps the maximum of "last 24 hours" and "since last login"? I'd prefer the last 24 hours to be the default too, but I see your point. Starting at either "24 hours ago" or "last login time" depending on which came first would be a good trade-off IMHO.

Comment: If *I* haven't logged in in the last 24 hours, then I'd have MUCH bigger problems than checking my SO Status :D Besides, people could still check "Last Week/Month". But maybe I am special in that I check SO daily.

Answer (score 4):

In the old one you would see comments and votes wrong and there was a difference between clicking the envelope and then clicking today.

I had a vote happen 3 hours ago (night time) and it's showing correctly. In the old version I would have also seen the other 3 votes I got before midnight. (A total of 4 votes)

Comment: Still inconsistent for me though, I've added screenshots now.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes to this page were rolled out last night, see Jeff's comments here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt/25650#25650