# Data inconsistency between "recent replies" and one question view

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563620/how-to-make-main-window-visible-in-cocoa) on SO. At this time, I am seeing two answers to it. However, when I click on my "envelope" icon in the top navigation bar (next to my name) and look at the "Most Recent Responses" section, I see three responses. There is a response there that I do not see in the "one topic" view, and it has been like this for several minutes. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look [very, very closely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25663/users-recent-page-does-not-consistently-show-all-changes/25722#25722) at the date and times at the top of the /users/recent page.

Edit: one of the answers was deleted by the owner. C'est la vie.

Edit 2: OK, I finally fixed that long standing bug, so deleted answers should not show up in your /user/recent

Comment: Thanks, I looked now. I don't get it. In "most recent responses", I see three responses, posted "31m" ago, "32m" ago and "37m" ago. 31m and 32m show up in the thread, 37m does not. How should I apply the date and times at the top of /users/recent to make more sense?

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it is now less confusing, I no longer see the deleted answer.