# Could we have static date range links on the Recent Activity page?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

The recent activity page only shows activity since last login until 23:59:59. I would ideally like the live titles to show everything from "Today", but there is no static link for Today at 00:00:00 to today at 23:59:59... a date range must be specified in the query string. For this reason, I can never have a bookmark that shows "Today".

I propose something like the following:

- /users/recent/[uid]?Today => Shows
  00:00:00 to 23:59:59
- /users/recent/[uid]?Yesterday =>
  Shows 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 from the
  previous day
- ..and so on for
  ThisWeek, LastWeek, ThisMonth,
  LastMonth.

Edit:
I've also come up with an alternative idea, which may (or may not) be easier to implement. In the query string, in addition to using [StartDate|EndDate]=YYYY-MM-DD, why not allow for the keywords above? ie. StartDate=Yesterday&EndDate=Today

This could also alleviate the troubles experienced by the following folks:

- [Why does the default time range on the ‘recent activity’ page work as it does?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/why-does-the-default-time-range-on-the-recent-activity-page-work-as-it-does)
- [/users/recent page does not consistently show all changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25663/users-recent-page-does-not-consistently-show-all-changes)

**Background:**

I am asking because I am using the reputation microsummaries for Firefox found here:

[Firefox users - your stackoverflow “reputation” microsummary!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/firefox-users-your-stackoverflow-reputation-microsummary)

I have the live title loaded from my default /users/recent/[uid] page. The microsummary will only show what can be pulled from a bookmarked page. If I bookmark the "today" page, it is always a constant date range.

One day left on bounty, maybe this is trivial for most folks.

Comment: Sounds like that Firefox addon could be improved.

Comment: What does it have to do with the addon? Microsummaries are a feature of Mozilla that allow the titles of bookmarks to be "live". If the URL always points to one location (ie date range in the query string) how is that in the scope of the addon to "change" it to the current date?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Completely misunderstood what this is all about.

Comment: No big deal =] I'll clarify in OP.

Comment: In what way is this `status-completed`? I realize I might have missed something, but I can't find a way to get an activity page for "yesterday" for whenever "yesterday" is that I visit the URL.

Comment: Aye.. I can't figure it out.