# Why does the default time range on the 'recent activity' page work as it does?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, timestamps

I just went to my 'Recent Activity' page on StackOverflow and the time range offered to me by default was:

```
2009-10-28 13:38:20Z to 2009-10-28 23:59:59Z

Top 5 Posts
(nothing in this date range)
Most Recent Responses
(nothing in this date range)

all times are in UTC; the current time is 2009-10-28 14:00:17Z
```

What is the logic that generates the range shown?

It means that I am being shown less than 20 minutes of activity plus about 8 hours of future time, which might be useful to Jon Skeet, but isn't to me (I don't often get significant voting activity in just the last 20 minutes) -- I always have to go and select 'Today' to get anything meaningful.

Can't you modify the code so that the range is more like one of these:

- 2009-10-28 00:00:00Z to 2009-10-28 23:59:59Z
- 2009-10-27 14:00:17Z to 2009-10-28 14:00:17Z

(In case it is not clear - the first alternative is 'the current 24 hours aligned to the day's ends in Zulu time', and the second is 'the last 24 hours as of the current time'; the first is the range provided when you do click 'Today'.)

Comment: I keep clicking the Today button to actually see SOMETHING, guess I shouldn't keep the SuperUser page open all the time...

Comment: Related post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/could-we-have-static-date-range-links-on-the-recent-activity-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer for an explanation:

[Clicking envelope beside username shows fewer recent activities than “today” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt)

The "startdate" by default is the time current time minus the time shown in the "Last activity" line of your profile.

Frankly, I wish the default were the values you get from clicking "Today".

Alternatively, upvote my feature request here, because it's a functionality that would satisfy your needs as well:

[Could we have static date range links on the Recent Activity page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/could-we-have-static-date-range-links-on-the-recent-activity-page)

Comment: Unfortunately using the "Last Activity" time as the start of the range is next to useless, because this value is not very accurate; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated

Comment: The x-ref is relevant - I think we're stuck with WAD (Working As Designed), but the design is misguided and the default is not sensible for the majority of users.  The name 'Today' doesn't help; it isn't 'Today' but 'Since last activity recorded', and still should not be the default.