# What time range is Recent Activity supposed to show?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**

Comment: What, you're GMT+12?

Comment: sounds like it's UTC+13 - which may or may not be +13 from London (depending on whether BST is in effect)

Comment: Daylight savings now, which means it's probably +13.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/why-does-the-default-time-range-on-the-recent-activity-page-work-as-it-does

Answer (score 2):

See: [Why does the default time range on the 'recent activity' page work as it does?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/why-does-the-default-time-range-on-the-recent-activity-page-work-as-it-does) for a discussion.

Roughly, it uses the last time you looked at the data as the start time for the interval.  If you go to the page repeatedly, you'll see some information, then no information, and then (if you've been given some rep or comments) some information again.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it by default shows activity during the current session.

Comment: @RickNZ: I'm not saying that this would be particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I always assumed it displays whatever happened since my last visit of the site. If yes, then there can be no fixed time range.

**Update 1:**
Example: If I visit the site in the morning and then again in the evening, I will get the highlighted envelope in the evening. Clicking on it I will be presented with any comments and answers I got since I was there in the morning.

**Update 2:**
I don't know where it is explained. To me this is quite intuitive.