# Make the Recent Activity Page easier to find

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

I have recently stumbled upon the filterable "Recent Activity" page.  I found it by clicking the envelope icon next to my user name.  This is different than the "Activity" tab on the user profile.

Is there another way to access it, besides this envelope icon?

This is a useful feature, and it seems it would be good to make it a little more explicit and obvious to find.

Comment: More prominent? It's on every page next to your name. You can hack the URL by hand into the address bar if you want so ...

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: You're right.  Prominent isn't the word I am looking for.  I guess explicit is the word?  Something that says to the user, "recent activity" (including reputation, and answer acceptance).  To me, the mailbox icon says, "replies to your comments, questions, or answers."  The tooltip makes the behavior of the envelope icon link even less obvious.

Comment: Look at suggestion Nr. 2 in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30832/what-time-range-is-recent-activity-supposed-to-show - Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: Something like that, yeah :)

Comment: @Ladybug: This has de-facto been accepted and completed.  What should I do with this question?

Comment: Leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The only other place you can find it is if you have new notifications sometimes you get the orange drop-down bar that will have a link to the Recent Activity page.

This is obviously harder to find, since it is hardly ever there...

Comment: If this proves to be accurate, I will accept it as the answer.  This is what I asked.  I did mean it to be a feature request, though.  It is hard to put a feature request in question form :)  Maybe this should be a community wiki?

Comment: @Merlyn, Don't worry about making feature requests questions here on Meta.  I edited the title of your question.  Please change it back if it doesn't reflect what you wanted to request.  And, don't worry about making it a Community Wiki.

Comment: Well, I figured out what you are talking about, but it doesn't really solve my feature request :)  Still will upvote, though.