# 'Recent' fails to show latest reputation points, comments etc. at times

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, localization

I tried to search for this and apparently there *isn't* any related features related to user timezone offsets which sorts of makes me think this isn't a localization bug but anyways:

At the very point of writing this, it's 18:37 local time ([I'm in Helsinki, Finland so that's EET or UTC/GMT+2h](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=101)). The `Summary` tab shows my `Recent activity` ([this URL to be exact](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/44523)) range as

> 2009-11-18 16:19:15Z to 2009-11-18
>   23:59:59Z

However both ranges (*Top 5 Posts* and *Most Recent Responses)* show

> (nothing in this date range)

which is clearly wrong since I've gained reputation during couple of last hours and I can actually find out that rep bo going to the `Reputation` tab, clicking yesterday, then back to today which **adds** range params to the URL ([click here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/44523?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2009-11-18&EndDate=2009-11-18)) and if I now click `Summary` tab, a whole bunch of params are added to the link ([click here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/44523?startdate=2009-11-18%2000%3a00%3a00z&enddate=2009-11-18%2023%3a59%3a59z&tab=summary#sort-top)) and everything works - until I return to the Summary once again by my default means by clicking the envelope icon.

This has occurred repeatedly (possibly daily) for some time now, always during this time of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/why-does-the-default-time-range-on-the-recent-activity-page-work-as-it-does) and [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/why-does-the-default-time-range-on-the-recent-activity-page-work-as-it-does/27596#27596) which I will repost for convenience:

> See this answer for an explanation:
>
> [Clicking envelope beside username
>   shows fewer recent activities than
>   “today” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt)
>
> The "startdate" by default is the time
>   current time minus the time shown in
>   the "Last activity" line of your
>   profile.
>
> Frankly, I wish the default were the
>   values you get from clicking "Today".
>
> Alternatively, upvote my feature
>   request here, because it's a
>   functionality that would satisfy your
>   needs as well:
>
> [Could we have static date range links
>   on the Recent Activity page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/could-we-have-static-date-range-links-on-the-recent-activity-page)

Comment: To me that's not expected behaviour but oh well, at least there's an explanation.

Comment: I agree, up the other answers.

Comment: That's opposite of what I see -- the default generally shows me *more* than today. Particularly shortly after midnight UTC (early evening for me, as I'm UTC-0800) I see events from both before UTC and after.